# Invalid pointer when deleting GLib.Tree elements in Vala

Tags: memory-management, glib, vala

This code causes the following error

`free(): invalid pointer`

[Online example](https://tio.run/##jVTbbtNAEH33V4wqIdmqcZPyUpEmAnoDWgqkoVyqKto442TB3jXrdUqL@u1h1vY6m1QU8mBv5nbOHM/sgqVsuSwLLmZwcsYnPW91joZMTGXW87ydHThJ5YSlsGCKs0mK3kgh7hdaUXAI1R8udAi1ZQADyBgXxk7peTlJeUw@pulFcZUT/Dr46hqYmhUB/PaAfoT1RnDNmUZQFQEoEKeVryYUFajHxga@X1K1Z7sBzMiUSSG1FDwea56hHwQ9W9ByIWxTOeV3xESKyt36@iDwBv7VV5SUaQq@zTqQWc4UHjLNjksRm6ohJOSonysKw6YVfke8E6kglTKvnOaPb0ThRKHTo9e@0WhMzc8Q/G6n0wnBPLsBObe3rVBWrAQYxFJMuQEHXkCGmgqaEy5QBG0wT4z5CexCn4DcMk2pA4VGdVb1DVqSIIUGKehk@11LeSiPJstInps0R043pNFvFfh/CroNiwKVtrNBnWs04hmWq6prSStzxOtk3xG4UrcbhE3Fi4ontOPzEFnPsSr5iDLW2OJt1A4dTg7OvVc/7dAcZbm@bfHWxjV6QXODLJ7TEljbKd6GbcAlS0sMoD9wvnObrDCTCwQ3k4aLEEdzGpuUC4SYlQUWNAzmK/jBc1J4QZszhVySeKgAlZKqLa1Ql0pAwtIC64buqTHPcXV63r1zF1RKbMjSUG2c8ZwpWnWapK2Xrw4Oj45PXr95e3r27vz9h4/Di9Gny89fvn5jk3iKyWzOv/9IMyHzn6rQ5eLm1@3dVs8tVr9GcliToZpb7W62c9/M1F4FzWLTZZ3310Xde7CSG0DbfdvH1frMNdYoRTHT8@A60nJcWCEaBV351uu6WhpKj@5TzZqFVeTEkjXXAaMWyNBAPO32HM/A8TSO9kvCBvwj16G95g1@c2oprFqLs5wwQ3JRZ8vlHw)

```
using GLib;
using GLib.Random;

// Global variable
Tree<string, Tree<int, string> > mainTree;

public static int main (string[] args) {
    // Initiate random seed
    Random.set_seed ((uint32) get_monotonic_time());
    // mainTree initialization
    mainTree = new Tree<string, Tree<int, string> >.full (mainTreeCompareDataFunction, free, free);
    // Random sized for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < int_range (1000, 10001); i++) {
        // If a condition is met (i is even)
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            // Create a Tree to nest onto mainTree
            Tree<int, string> treeToNest = new Tree<int, string>.full (treeToNestCompareDataFunction, free, free);
            // Insert random content into treeToNest
            treeToNest.insert (int_range (0, 101), randomString ());
            // Insert the tree onto mainTree
            mainTree.insert (randomString (), treeToNest);
        }
    }

    // Empty the tree
    mainTree.@foreach ((mainTreeKey, mainTreeValue) => {
        mainTree.remove (mainTreeKey); // This line causes a free(): invalid pointer error
        return false;
    });

    return 0;
}

public string randomString () {
    string charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string stringToReturn = "";
    // Create a random 8 character string
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        stringToReturn += charset[int_range (0, charset.length)].to_string ();
    }
    return stringToReturn;
}

public int treeToNestCompareDataFunction (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0; 
}

public int mainTreeCompareDataFunction (string a, string b) {
    return strcmp (a, b);
}
```

I suspect that it is because there is a nested `GLib.Tree` inside the tree and `free()` cannot be used on those objects. If I use `null` instead for the destroy function for the values of `mainTree`, no crash happens, but a memory leak is created if I were to reuse the `mainTree` variable.

Is there any way to empty the tree and have the memory freed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a lambda that will delete the sub tree using an ownership transfer.

```
    mainTree = new Tree<string, Tree<int, string> >.full (mainTreeCompareDataFunction, free,
        (data) => {
          var tree = (Tree<string, Tree<int, string>>) data;
          // Ownership is transfered to this local var which calls unref when it goes out of scope
          var tree2 = (owned) tree;
        });
```

Here is the full code:

```
using GLib;
using GLib.Random;

// Global variable
Tree<string, Tree<int, string> > mainTree;

public static int main (string[] args) {
    // Initiate random seed
    Random.set_seed ((uint32) get_monotonic_time());
    // mainTree initialization
    mainTree = new Tree<string, Tree<int, string> >.full (mainTreeCompareDataFunction, free,
        (data) => {
          var tree = (Tree<string, Tree<int, string>>) data;
          // Ownership is transfered to this local var which calls unref when it goes out of scope
          var tree2 = (owned) tree;
        });
    // Random sized for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < int_range (1000, 10001); i++) {
        // If a condition is met (i is even)
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            // Create a Tree to nest onto mainTree
            Tree<int, string> treeToNest = new Tree<int, string>.full (treeToNestCompareDataFunction, null, free);
            // Insert random content into treeToNest
            treeToNest.insert (int_range (0, 101), randomString ());
            // Insert the tree onto mainTree
            mainTree.insert (randomString (), treeToNest);
        }
    }

    // Empty the tree
    mainTree.@foreach ((mainTreeKey, mainTreeValue) => {
        mainTree.remove (mainTreeKey);
        return false;
    });

    return 0;
}

public string randomString () {
    string charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string stringToReturn = "";
    // Create a random 8 character string
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        stringToReturn += charset[int_range (0, charset.length)].to_string ();
    }
    return stringToReturn;
}

public int treeToNestCompareDataFunction (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0; 
}

public int mainTreeCompareDataFunction (string a, string b) {
    return strcmp (a, b);
}
```

I would avoid using the GLib.Tree class in Vala, because of the difficulty to get the memory management right. You should consider using a `Gee.TreeMap` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works better that way. I'm not using Gee.TreeMap since it was giving me memory leaks as the nested Gee.TreeMap was stored as a `gconstpointer` due to the Gee library's implementation on how keys and values are stored in the map and it wouldn't free the memory pointed by it when clearing the tree. In the `gee.h` file it can be seen that it uses gconstpointers to store keys and data on the tree. This same code, but using instead Gee.TreeMap shows 'possibly lost' values in valgrind and many more steps to insert data into a Tree which slows down the program.

Comment: Ok, If you haven't already you should write a bug report for libgee then.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution which is to do manual memory management. First, make the nested tree a **pointer**. Second, pass `null` to the argument for specifying the function for freeing the nested tree. Third, pass `null` to the argument for specifying the function for freeing the `int` keys of the nested tree. Finally, use the `delete` keyword for decrementing the reference to the nested tree when emptying the main tree.

Because the reference to the nested tree will fall to 0 in this code due to the manual call of `delete` which **here specifically** calls `g_tree_unref` in the Vala generated C code, all keys and values of the nested tree are destroyed and all memory allocated by the tree is released. That way no invalid pointer errors happen anymore and no memory leaks either.

```
using GLib;
using GLib.Random;

// Global variable
Tree<string, Tree<int, string>* > mainTree;

public static int main (string[] args) {
    // Initiate random seed
    Random.set_seed ((uint32) get_monotonic_time());
    // mainTree initialization
    mainTree = new Tree<string, Tree<int, string> >.full (mainTreeCompareDataFunction, free, null);
    // Random sized for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < int_range (1000, 10001); i++) {
        // If a condition is met (i is even)
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            // Create a Tree to nest onto mainTree
            Tree<int, string>* treeToNest = new Tree<int, string>.full (treeToNestCompareDataFunction, null, free);
            // Insert random content into treeToNest
            treeToNest->insert (int_range (0, 101), randomString ());
            // Insert the tree onto mainTree
            mainTree.insert (randomString (), treeToNest);
        }
    }

    // Empty the tree
    mainTree.@foreach ((mainTreeKey, mainTreeValue) => {
        delete mainTree.lookup (mainTreeKey);
        mainTree.remove (mainTreeKey);
        return false;
    });

    return 0;
}

public string randomString () {
    string charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string stringToReturn = "";
    // Create a random 8 character string
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        stringToReturn += charset[int_range (0, charset.length)].to_string ();
    }
    return stringToReturn;
}

public int treeToNestCompareDataFunction (int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0; 
}

public int mainTreeCompareDataFunction (string a, string b) {
    return strcmp (a, b);
}
```

Sources:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling#Manual_memory_management_with_pointer_syntax
- https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-unref

Comment: While manual memory management works, it is considered a last resort solution in Vala.